# How does Optimus Prime know how Captain Witwicky found Megatron?

Tags: transformers, transformers-2007

In *Transformers*, after Autobots reveal themselves to Mikaela and Sam, Optimus tells them about how Cybertron got destroyed by Megatron and Decepticons. Then he proceeds to tell them how Sam's great-great-grandfather found Megatron in the North Pole pretty detailed like how *it was an accident* and how *by mistake, he activated Megatron's navigation system*.

How can he know all that? Even if it is somehow written in the Sector 7's top secret files (which is unlikely), Autobots never accessed to the P.O.T.U.S. or any other military/government network by that point.

Answer (score 7):

But this *is* a matter of public record. According to Sam's show-and-tell in class:

> Unfortunately, my great-great-grandfather, the genius that he was, wound up going blind and crazy in a psycho ward, drawing these strange symbols and babbling on about some giant ice man that he thought he'd discovered.

He then shows a news article about it. Presumably, his great-great-grandfather told the details *there*, it's just that no one believed him. But the Autobots could've easily accessed the story (they mention themselves that they learned English online).

[image]

Comment: Yes but is the story itself available online? What did they search for? Sam brings actual newspapers not digital records (doesn't mean that they don't exist). And Decepticons had to hack into POTUS to learn about Captain Witwicky's story. Wouldn't they simply search the internet as well?

Comment: Good questions, but I don't think they're answered in the movie, for the most part. The paper looks like *The New York Times*, which indeed has a complete online archive dating back to 1851. As for the Decepticons' choices - different methods, I guess. The Autobots did their homework while the bad guys chose to get the information by force (and remember they were also looking for *Megatron* as well as the Allspark).